# Query optimization to get Gender count base on where clauses

Tags: mysql, optimization

I would like to optimize my query performance to get gender count based on where clause. I already know indexing will add performance and updating my category to a certain value to tag such where clause. But first would like to check first if someone can help me optimize first the query before doing indexing and updating. Thank a bunch.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN colVal = 1 THEN 'Male' 
         WHEN colVal = 2 THEN 'Female' 
    END AS `range` ,
    COUNT(*) AS `count` ,
    CASE WHEN colVal = 1 THEN '1' 
         WHEN colVal = 2 THEN '2' 
    END AS 'sort' 
FROM ( SELECT SUM(FI.gender_farmer) as colVal 
       FROM anReference as RF 
         INNER JOIN anFarmerInfo as FI using (ref_id) 
         INNER JOIN anFieldInfo as F using (ref_id) 
         INNER JOIN anSessionExtension as SE using (ref_id) 
         INNER JOIN anExtensionInfo as EI using (extension_id) 
         INNER JOIN tblProvince as LP USING (province_id) 
       WHERE FI.gender_farmer!=0 
         AND RF.date_accessed between '2013-1-1 00:00:00' AND '2015-4-29 23:59:59' 
         AND FI.farmer_name NOT LIKE '%test%' 
         AND FI.farmer_name NOT LIKE '.' 
         AND FI.farmer_name NOT LIKE '' 
         AND FI.farmer_email NOT LIKE '%@email.com%' 
         AND F.field_name NOT LIKE '%test%' 
         AND F.field_name NOT LIKE '.' 
         AND F.field_name NOT LIKE '..' 
         AND EI.extension_email NOT LIKE '%@email.com%' 
         AND EI.extension_name NOT LIKE '%test%' 
         AND EI.extension_name NOT LIKE 'n/a' 
         AND EI.extension_name NOT LIKE 'na' 
         AND EI.extension_name NOT LIKE 'n.a.' 
         AND EI.extension_name NOT LIKE '.' 
         AND EI.extension_name NOT LIKE'' 
         AND CHAR_LENGTH(EI.extension_name)>=2 
         AND RF.category IN (0,5) 
         AND RF.test=1 
       GROUP BY ref_id ) AS summary 
GROUP BY `sort` 
ORDER BY LENGTH(`sort`), `sort`
```

Comment: I think `LIKE '.' ` is same as `= '.'` so at first try to change them, then use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` but in a correct order and I think with your clauses `Null` values will remove  ;).

Comment: When you have `CHAR_LENGTH(EI.extension_name)>=2`, you can remove `EI.extension_name NOT LIKE '.'` and `EI.extension_name NOT LIKE ''` and `EI.extension_name NOT LIKE 'na'` clauses.

Comment: Thanks guys this is a great help. But it doesn't seem to improve the query time.. ;)

Comment: Please use `ORDER BY colVal` instead of `ORDER BY LENGTH(sort), sort`, and `GROUP BY colVal` instead of `GROUP BY sort`.

Comment: GIGO.  Get rid of the rows with all the junk; then you want have to filter them out.